# flutter app ios archive fails with "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation."

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I am running the archive process of my flutter app in xcode.

The build is failing with error 'The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.'.

I have deleted my Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods folder. I have then run 'flutter pub get', then 'pod install' and 'pod update'. I then ran 'flutter run' and 'flutter build ios', which both succeed.

After all this, the archive process fails with the same error.